# Does muscovite occur as a contact metamorphism mineral?

Tags: mineralogy, metamorphism

Does muscovite occur as a contact metamorphism mineral, with dacitic intrusion into dacitic rocks?

Comment: About your specific question of a dacitic intrusion into dacitic rocks, metadacites can have muscovite. That means the chemistry of dacites as protolyte can develop muscovite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, wikipedia page for muscovite tells:

> Muscovite is the most common mica, found in granites, pegmatites,
> gneisses, and schists, **and as a contact metamorphic rock** or as a
> secondary mineral resulting from the alteration of topaz, feldspar,
> kyanite, etc.
>
> Source: [Muscovite, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscovite).

As always, you need to corroborate wikipedia is correct, but there are several papers that talk about muscovite on contact metamorphism environments, you can do your own search on a scientifical database.

[Here is an example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016703775901349) about a paper that deals with muscovite found on contact aureole of Duluth Complex, Minnesota.

So yes it is a mineral phase formed in that conditions of increased temperature due to an intrusion.

For you specific question about contact metadacites, yes too, they can develop muscovite as shown in [this book](https://books.google.es/books?id=bOZHx7ITq24C&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=dacite%20muscovite&source=bl&ots=d0nxV_LnYT&sig=ACfU3U1UEf1HghTYFbmWmZBKq29QbkFPzg&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0uObtiOrkAhWqDmMBHZm2BVAQ6AEwEHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=dacite%20muscovite&f=false) about US geology.